# How to convert Cell-based table into View-based table in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

I'm having hard time understanding how to implement view-based table in cocoa. Right now I have working implementation of old-fashioned cell-based table. As I figured out, just dragging the NSTableCellView onto my columns in a NIB file won't make my table view-based :)

I read through this article: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableViewOverview/TableViewOverview.html

But still clueless...for some reason my tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: method is not getting hit.

Can some one give me step by step explanations on how can I convert my cell-based table to view-based?

In my cell-based table I have:

```
// .h
#import "ObjectClass.h"
#import "ObjectTable.h"

@interface ObjViewController : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet ObjectTable *objectTable;
    NSMutableArray *list;
    ObjViewController *current;
}  

//.m
#import "ObjViewController.h"

@implementation ObjViewController

-(id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {
       current = self;
       list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }

   return self;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [list count];
}

-(id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                                                               row:(NSInteger)row
{
    ObjectClass *obj = [list objectAtIndex:row];

    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

    return [obj valueForKey: identifier];
}

// .h
@interface ObjectClass : NSObject
{
}
@property int categoryID;
@property int oID;
@property NSString *name;

@end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method

```
tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:
```

Is from the NSTableViewDelegate protocol and once implemented will make the NSTableView a view-based table. From the code above, the view controller is not conforming to the NSTableViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: you're right...but I just missed it when I was posting the question...I have it In my code. Just edited it here too. Good catch!

Comment: Did you make sure to set the delegate of the view to the view controller? I can't think of other reasons why it wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've changed the Content Mode for your table in IB (Attributes Inspector). You want View Based, not Cell Based.

Comment: It changes automatically as you drag&drop  NSTableCellView onto your table column, but thank you for your response!